# Iteratively deleting files of a specific type

Tags: for-loop, unix

I have subfolders with .tmp files that I wish to delete, and trying to find a one-liner for doing so.

```
for item in folder1/*/*; do rm *.tmp; done
```

From this I get a bunch of messages saying:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘*.tmp’: No such file or directory
```

I get the same problem when I try doing other operations. What am I missing here?

P.S. I know I could recursively delete without a for loop with `rm -rf *.tmp` but I would like to know how to do it using an iterative loop, so that I can use it to perform other actions apart from `rm` by just replacing the "action" part of the statement.

Thanks in advance,

Jan

Comment: it's check in **every** directory for `*.tmp`. When it **doesn't** find any `.tmp` files, the shell returns `*.tmp`, and `rm` uses that as an argument and hence generates an error message because there **isn't** a file literally name `*.tmp` (which is a legal filename). To see what is being deleted, you have to run `rm -i *.tmp`, but then it was ask you to confirm deletion of **every** existing `tmp` file. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
find folder1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.tmp" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This is going to find files (-type f) in the second directory level only (-mindept 2 -maxdepth 2) which name end with "tmp", and delete them.

You can try with "ls" instead of "rm" first, to check if the command is finding what you are looking for.